# DecisionTreeRegressor 'tree_' attribute documentation (Tree class)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to find the documentation on the 'Tree' class which is the class of the 'tree_' parameter of a 'DecisionTreeRegressor' but no success.

Would anybody know if this class is documented anywhere please ?

Thanks,
Yoann

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking in the following file but I am still interested to know if the Tree class is part of the documentation.

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/tree.py